# How to run the PHP and/or CodeIgniter function continuously

Tags: php, mysql, curl, codeigniter-2, foursquare

I am working on the location-based social networking website where I am integrating the [foursquare](https://foursquare.com/). I have used login with the foursquare, whenever the user login with his foursquare account I get his access token by using this I get his all data from the foursquare account which is very large and takes lot of time. That's why I am looking for a solution which will retrieve the foursquare data continuously in cycle.

Is there any way to `run the codeIgniter or PHP function continuously` to update the all users data `instead of updating the data scheduled basic like using cronjob`, it should run like once I run the function it will run infinite time without stop.

Note:

I am using `CURL` to get the data from the foursquare

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can write a simple PHP script like following and run this script by scheduling it in a cron job and then once this script runs, delete the cron tab (the script will keep runing):

```
while (true)
{
    // Setup your CURL request for foursquare
    // Fire the CURL request and get the results
    // do the processing
    // You can probably put a sleep here before it again   loops
    // Here is the magic to break the infinite loop - check a
    // variable from database table or from some ini file and break the loop
    // if the variable is set
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to daemonize PHP process, I've done this in past, and honestly can not remember what I've used, but quick google search gave me http://pear.php.net/package/System_Daemon .

What I can tell you is that PHP is not a good choice for this kind of things. I've had a huge amount of issues, that were directly related to the fact that PHP process was working all the time. Eventually, I rewrote that to Java (and http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/jsvc.html)

You can also take a look at job servers, for example Gearman (http://gearman.org/) is well known. Here is Gearman PHP lib http://php.net/manual/en/book.gearman.php .

I personally have used http://www.celeryproject.org/ for these kind of tasks (since the tasks can be scheduled, and manually triggered).